# MP3 file format Details

Tags: android, testing, mp3, media, file-format

I am trying to create media files required for android mediaframeworktest. In the file list they have given

PD_256kbps_44.1khz_mono_CBR_DPA.mp3
NIN_256kbps_44.1khz_mono_CBR_MCA.mp3 etc

Anybody know what is NIN...MCA and PD...DPA? are they just names or any special format of mp3?

Please explain.

Thanks
JSE

Comment: They are just type of MP3. There also can be also PD...MCA and WC....DPA or other.

Comment: Thanks... Where can I get more information about them?

Comment: @JSE: To know all media type names: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/com/android/mediaframeworktest/MediaNames.java

Comment: I am trying to create files listed in MediaNames.java :(

Comment: Do you want save recording in MP3 format? Whats your aim?

Comment: I am using audacity to convert files. I want know whether the NIN/PD/MCA/DPA are something related to mp3. According to Sen they are just names...

Comment: @JSE: They are just supportive information of mp3 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CBR - Constant Bit Rate
VBR -  Variable Bit Rate

---

I am not sure of these info, but please check.
I think they are just names. It has nothing got do with mp3 as a format

PD - Perception Digital
NIN - Nine Inch Nails

MCA and DPA are just some Company names

Just go through this [file](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/com/android/mediaframeworktest/MediaNames.java), you can see more.. :-)

Comment: Thanks... But I am trying to create files listed in MediaNames.java. I couldn't get any other details about the files except names !

Comment: PD_256kbps_44.1khz_mono_CBR_DPA.mp3 means that audio is having a bit rate of 256 kilo bits per second, a sampling rate of 44100 Hz, with Constant Bit rate and single channel output(mono)

Comment: __But I am trying to create files listed in MediaNames.java__ I dont understand what your are trying to do..

Comment: I just want know whether the NIN/PD/MCA/DPA are something related to mp3... Looks like they are band name and song name

Comment: @JSE : i agree with you.. you only need to take care of bit rate, sampling rate , and number of output channel

Comment: @JSE: I totally agree with Sen you don't need to care about extra information. It may not halt your code.

Comment: Thanks... I will just ignore those things.